# Обновить значение ячейки если новое значение не null

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть такой SQL запрос

```
UPDATE orders SET phone = '$phone', addr = '$addr', email = '$email', status = '$status', payment_meth = '$payment_meth', id_transaction = '$id_transaction'
```

Как добавить проверку в запрос на то, что переменные $phone, $email... не пустые? Задача обновлять ячейки только не пустыми данными.

Что-то вроде такого:

```
UPDATE orders SET phone = if ('$phone' != "" else phone)
```

Благодарю!

Comment: а вы добавьте ее не в запрос, а в вызывающий код. или оберните в `coalesce(:phone, phone)`

Comment: То, что параметры проверяются на "не-пустость" на сервере БД, не означает, что эту проверку не нужно делать на стороне клиента. Проверка в БД - это последняя линия обороны. Которую, кстати, разумно подкрепить NOT NULL атрибутом в соотв. полях структуры, а если версия сервера позволяет, то ещё и CHECK CONSTRAINT.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно делают через `COALESCE`:

```sql
phone = COALESCE('$phone', phone)
```

Если же интересует сравнение именно с пустой строкой, а не с `NULL`, то `CASE`:

```sql
phone = CASE WHEN '$phone' = '' THEN phone ELSE '$phone' END
```

Вариант для `NULL`, `''`, и строк с пробелами из комментариев:

```sql
phone = CASE WHEN TRIM('$phone') <> '' THEN '$phone' ELSE phone END
```

Comment: `'$phone'`  будет равен `''`, что не есть `null`

Comment: Добавил вариант с `CASE`.

Comment: Разумнее сразу дать вариант, который и на пустую строку (включая пробельную), и на NULL отреагирует одинаково. Т.е. `WHEN TRIM('$phone') != ''`.

Comment: @Akina ЕМНИП, `TRIM(NULL) IS NULL`. Тогда уж `TRIM(COALESCE(?, '')) = ''`.

Comment: Смотрите внимательнее - у меня НЕравенство `!=`. Поэтому и NULL, и пустая строка, и пробельная строка - пролетят в ELSE.

Comment: Допёрло. Вставил.